# Content Control not recognizing content

Tags: vba, error-handling, ms-word, controls

I was hoping someone could help me work out why the the 'F' value in my code below continues to include my error label in the ErrorMessage String when the Count value is 5?

In the document, the content control contains text just like all the other controls (which work perfectly) but this content Control text value is not being recognised in the VBA code to map error labels.

Have tried just replacing the control and checking the properties match. Debug messages suggest the the value is just being set to the default Content Control Value of "Click or Tap here to input text".

```
Private Sub Create_Click()
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oCC2 As ContentControl

Dim Mandatory(9) As String
Dim ErrorMessage As String
Dim ErrorCount As Integer
Dim ErrorLabel(9) As String

Dim objDoc As Document
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFileString As String
Dim Number As String

Mandatory(0) = "A"
Mandatory(1) = "B"
Mandatory(2) = "C"
Mandatory(3) = "D"
Mandatory(4) = "E"
Mandatory(5) = "F"
Mandatory(6) = "G"
Mandatory(7) = "H"
Mandatory(8) = "I"

ErrorLabel(0) = "A Label"
ErrorLabel(1) = "B Label"
ErrorLabel(2) = "C Label"
ErrorLabel(3) = "D Label"
ErrorLabel(4) = "E Label"
ErrorLabel(5) = "F Label"
ErrorLabel(6) = "G Label"
ErrorLabel(7) = "H Label"
ErrorLabel(8) = "I Label"

ErrorMessage = ""

ErrorMessage = "The following mandatory fields are missing: "

For Count = 0 To 8

   Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(Mandatory(Count)).Item(1)
   MsgBox (oCC.Range.Text)


   If Count = 0 Then

      Number = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(Mandatory(Count)).Item(1).Range.Text

   End If

   If oCC.Range.Text = "Click or tap here to enter text." Or oCC.Range.Text = "0.00" Then
   
      ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "- " & ErrorLabel(Count)
      MsgBox (oCC.Range.Text)

      ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
    
   End If
Next Count

If ErrorCount > 0 Then

  MsgBox (ErrorMessage)

Else

  strFileString = Number

  MsgBox (strFileString)

  strFilename = "Some Text Here" & " - " & strFileString & ".pdf"

  With ActiveDocument

    NewPath = .Path & "\" & strFilename
 .SaveAs2 FileName:=NewPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
 .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFilename, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
 OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
 Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent

 End With
 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share the purpose of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Check there are no other content controls with the same title in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test your code for lack of data but from your description I guess that the ErrorMessage must be reset with each loop since it will be changed when used and would naturally retain the modified version thereafter.

Except for what follows the loop, I looked closely at your code in order to understand it. Perhaps, the changes I made will be of some use to you.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Create_Click()

    Dim Doc             As Document
    Dim Mandatory()     As String
    Dim ErrorMessage    As String
    Dim ErrorCount      As Integer
    Dim strFilename     As String
    Dim strFileString   As String               ' this appears identical with 'Number'
    Dim Number          As String
    Dim Count           As Integer              ' loop counter
    
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Mandatory = Split("A B C D E F G H I")
    Number = Doc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(Mandatory(0))(1).Range.Text

    For Count = 1 To UBound(Mandatory) + 1
        ErrorMessage = "The following mandatory fields are missing: "
        With Doc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(Mandatory(Count))(1).Range
            MsgBox "Number = " & Number & vbCr & .Text
            If .Text = "Click or tap here to enter text." Or _
               .Text = "0.00" Then
                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "- " & Mandatory(Count) & " Label"
                MsgBox (.Text)
                ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
            End If
        End With
        If Count = 1 Then Exit For
    Next Count
    
    If ErrorCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox (ErrorMessage)
    Else
        strFileString = Number
        MsgBox (strFileString)
        strFilename = "Some Text Here" & " - " & strFileString & ".pdf"

        With Doc
            NewPath = .Path & "\" & strFilename
            .SaveAs2 FileName:=NewPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
            .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFilename, _
                                 ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                 OpenAfterExport:=True, _
                                 OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                 Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                 Item:=wdExportDocumentContent
        End With
    End If
 End Sub
```

You can have VBA add the useful (some would say necessary) *Option Explicit* to all new code modules automatically. Select Tools > Options in the VBE window and check "Require Variable Declaration" on the *Editor* tab.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! i have taken some of this code and applied it to mine so much appreciated. Forgot about L/UBound. i determined the issue was i had other content controls i had copied with the same titlename as the F content control. duh! Therefore it was counting these as an error. On changing the titles, my code works perfectly. Thanks for your help.